# why alert box is not appear when click on edit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my code there is a div tag having class of  `class = specific` and in the div there are two tags `,. In span there is some text and the anchor tag be seems like below:-

```
<a class="editByAnchor" id="0" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#thirdModal">
  <i class="fa fa-edit">
  </i>
</a>
```

Modal

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="thirdModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body" style="margin: -1px;">
                <div class= "content"></div>
                <div id="specific_dates"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"  data-dismiss="modal">Update</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

When I click on the icon then I put there is a hello alert box with the help of the jQuery. but it does not work.

Code jQuery:-

```
$('.editByAnchor').on('click', function() {
    alert("hello");     
});
```

Why it doesn't show the alert box. Thank you.

Comment: it's working for me. What is your error ? Anything is shown in console ?

Comment: did you jquery source file in script tag? did you add in this format                         $( document ).ready(function() {
    //your code
'});

Comment: recheck, works fine. may be you dont include the library, show whats on the console

Comment: @melvin it shows me modal only

Comment: @MigratedPigeon i used it in my jQuery. yeah everything is in the position

Comment: vikas post your entire html file

Comment: check this https://jsfiddle.net/melvinstanly/21u1pLgf/ @vikaskumar

Comment: @akhilaravind I checked it many times

Comment: Create a [MCVE]. The fragmented code shown isn't enough to decipher the problem.

Comment: @melvin use modal too

Comment: isn't there any error in console ? @vikaskumar

Comment: do you want the alert box instead of modal, on click of the icon?

Comment: couldn't get your requirement. Do you want alert on clicking what ? what to do with modal ?

Comment: below answers working well but I don't know why it is not working in my code :(

Comment: @melvin I just want to display something in the modal but with jQuery if alert box display then i Will move something new task

Comment: @vikaskumar so you got the answer ?

Comment: @melvin no but for this question i choose It but actually it is not working this anchor tag is created dynamically using ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add your code in `$(document).ready(function(){`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.editByAnchor').on('click', function() {
      alert("hello");     
   });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<a class="editByAnchor" id="0" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#thirdModal">
  <i class="fa fa-edit">
  </i>Button
</a>
<div class="modal fade" id="thirdModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body" style="margin: -1px;">
            <div class= "content"></div>
            <div id="specific_dates"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"  data-dismiss="modal">Update</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your JavaScript function to the below one. everything else looks fine.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.editByAnchor').on('click', function() {
  alert("hello");     
     });
  });
```

This makes sure your code binds after all the scripts have been loaded.